# Creating a hierarchy array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am almost finished with the JavaScript code to create my final array of JSON formatted objects.
From my source array, I have created a top-level parent and its respective child records.

I now need to push additional records onto one of more child records. Here's where I'm having trouble.

Here is my target data, where "id": 29 being my top-level node. Then the "children" array falls below :

```
 [
  {
    "id": 29,
    "field0": "$ALL$",
    "field1": 1564.92711931719,
    "field2": -171.934775655824,
    "field3": -292.877167373888,
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "field0": "Goldman",
            "field1": 0,
            "field2": 0,
            "field3": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "field0": "IBM",
            "field1": 0,
            "field2": 0,
            "field3": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "field0": "JP Chase",
            "field1": 0,
            "field2": 0,
            "field3": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "field0": "Merrill",
            "field1": 0,
            "field2": 0,
            "field3": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "field0": "Nokia",
            "field1": 0,
            "field2": 0,
            "field3": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "field0": "Pequot",
            "field1": 0,
            "field2": 0,
            "field3": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "field0": "Deutsche",
            "field1": 0,
            "field2": 0,
            "field3": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "field0": "General Insurance",
            "field1": 0,
            "field2": 0,
            "field3": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 18,
            "field0": "AIG",
            "field1": 0,
            "field2": 0,
            "field3": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 19,
            "field0": "Andor",
            "field1": 0,
            "field2": 0,
            "field3": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 20,
            "field0": "BARCLAYS",
            "field1": 92.7731197209214,
            "field2": -10.1717767200607,
            "field3": 616.369427825382
        },
        {
            "id": 26,
            "field0": "CSFB",
            "field1": 3.35029024626419,
            "field2": -0.367366071961442,
            "field3": -132.725310207512
        },
        {
            "id": 27,
            "field0": "BLOSOFL",
            "field1": 0,
            "field2": 0,
            "field3": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 28,
            "field0": "GRMOBND",
            "field1": 0,
            "field2": 0,
            "field3": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 32,
            "field0": "GM",
            "field1": 0,
            "field2": 0,
            "field3": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 33,
            "field0": "GE",
            "field1": 0,
            "field2": 0,
            "field3": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 34,
            "field0": "BHPBMGRP",
            "field1": 1468.80370935,
            "field2": -161.395632863801,
            "field3": -776.521284991759                
        },
        {
            "id": 35,
            "field0": "PIMCO",
            "field1": 0,
            "field2": 0,
            "field3": 0
        }
    ]
  }
 ]
```

I am now left with the following leftover source array, where I need to find its parent record above.

```
[   
{
    "id": 7,
    "parent": 35,
    "values": [
        "Pimco Fund A",
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
},

{
    "id": 15,
    "parent": 0,
    "values": [
        "GSAM",
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
},
{
    "id": 17,
    "parent": 33,
    "values": [
        "Genworth",
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
},
{
    "id": 21,
    "parent": 30,
    "values": [
        "BHHSH",
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
},
{
    "id": 22,
    "parent": 30,
    "values": [
        "BHPBFIN",
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
},
{
    "id": 23,
    "parent": 31,
    "values": [
        "BHPSTEEUR",
        1468.80370935,
        -161.395632863801,
        -776.521284991759
    ]
},
{
    "id": 25,
    "parent": 31,
    "values": [
        "BLUESCOPEFIN",
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
},
{
    "id": 30,
    "parent": 34,
    "values": [
        "BHPBGRP",
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
},
{
    "id": 31,
    "parent": 34,
    "values": [
        "BHPSTEELGRP",
        1468.80370935,
        -161.395632863801,
        -776.521284991759
    ]
}
```

]

I can use the UnderscoreJS library to locate each item in my "leftover", but how to push them onto my parents[] array ?

UPDATE:

Here's my _.each() loop, which is finally creating the children; however, I still have some strays in my leftover array which will essentially end up being children of children (n-level hierarchy)

```
findPar["children"] = thisChild[0];
```

I believe there's a smarter way of accomplishing this.

```
       var findPar;
        _.each(rowsNew, function (row) {
              // looks through parents array where id == row.parent
            findPar = _.findWhere(parents[0].children, { id: row.parent }); 
            if (findPar != undefined) {                          
                if (findPar.children == undefined) {
                    findPar["children"] = createJsonFromSingleRow(row);
                }
                else {
                    findPar.children.push(createJsonFields(row));
                }
                rowsNew = _.reject(rowsNew, function (rec) { return rec.id == row.id;  });                }
        });
        return newJson = parents;
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Bob

Answer (score 2):

If you use objects with the `id` as the property name instead of arrays, this gets a bit simpler.  (You could create a function to do this conversion from the raw JSON object)

```
var hash = {
  '29' : {
    "id": 29,
    "field0": "$ALL$",
    "field1": 1564.92711931719,
    "field2": -171.934775655824,
    "field3": -292.877167373888,
    "children": {
        '0': {
            "id": 0,
            "field0": "Goldman",
            "field1": 0,
            "field2": 0,
            "field3": 0
        },
        '1': {
            "id": 1,
            "field0": "IBM",
            "field1": 0,
            "field2": 0,
            "field3": 0
        },
        ...
        '35': {
            "id": 35,
            "field0": "PIMCO",
            "field1": 0,
            "field2": 0,
            "field3": 0
        }
    }
  }
 };
```

Then you can add each leftover into the parents hash like this (using plain JS and assuming you've already found and populated the leftovers with a similar hash structure):

```
for( key in leftovers ){
  if( leftovers.hasOwnProperty(key) ){
    var parent = leftovers[key].parent;

    // If parent doesn't exist, create it
    if( !parent in hash ) {
      hash[parent] = { 
        id: parent,
        children: {}
      };
    }

    // Create the children object if it doesn't exist
    if( !hash[parent].children ) {
      hash[parent].children = {};
    }

    // Copy the object from leftovers into the parent hash
    // copyObj is custom and I didn't include it here.
    hash[parent].children[key] = copyObj(leftovers[key]);  

    // Remove from leftovers, now that it's moved to the parent hash.
    delete leftovers[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: So "key" will automatically pull the "id" field from leftovers ?

Comment: It doesn't pull the `id` field, it uses the property name, which you have to set to be the same as `id`.  As long as it's unique, it'll be fine.